# Login authentication like Netflix multiple users for same account in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I'm creating an trading app in flutter
Imagine that if an user account has an multiple login from different mobile devices if any one the user can change the account password how can I logout from all other user of different device

Or plz instruct me to create an logine authentication like instagram if an user logged in from another device change a password it will automatically logout from other device

Comment: What login are you using? Firebase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I see this is that Firebase doesn't allow you to implement this functionality right now so you'll have to get creative with this by :

1. Keep track of all the devices through **name** or **IMEI** from which logins of a particular user is happening
2. Create a boolean `isSignedOutAll` for each and every user and check for this at startup
3. Turn this to true if a user is clicking on **Sign Out Of All Devices** option
4. Logout the user if `isSignedOutAll` is true on a particular device and then change it back to false for that particular device

[image]

This is the solution that I can think of now.